# how to store values in jtable without a database in java

Tags: java, sql

```
private void bt_commit1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
        try {

            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dbo.bk_det(rm_id,bk_name,bk_branch) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            String rm = (tf_rm_id.getText().trim() == null || tf_rm_id.getText().equals("")) ? "0" : tf_rm_id.getText();
            String a = (txtbkname.getText().trim() == null || txtbkname.getText().equals("")) ? "UNKNOWN" : txtbkname.getText();
            String b = (txtbkbranch.getText().trim() == null || txtbkbranch.getText().equals("")) ? "UNKNOWN" : txtbkbranch.getText();

            stmt.setString(1, ""+(rm));
            stmt.setString(2, ""+(a));
            stmt.setString(3, ""+(b));

            stmt.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "COMMITED SUCCESSFULLY!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

i actually want to store the values in table without using the sql database. here i am using the sql statements to connect to my data base but i want to store the values from my java gui in netbeans to jtabel without a database

Comment: A `JTable` is used to display (and edit) data. If you don't want that data to be read from a database, where should that data come from?

Comment: JTable is a gui component - a visual representation of the data, not a  place to store data. Netbeans is an IDE - a development tool, the choice of which has no bearing on the question, if there is one.

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a reasonably detailed overview of JTable. As already stated, "JTable does not contain or cache data; it is simply a view of your data"

Answer (score 0):

Since JTable is a GUI component, you cannot store values in it. It only renders them. Once each reference to that component is lost, there's no way you can hold your information.

On the other hand, Netbeans it's just an IDE, like eclipse or others. You can draw a JTable components on its editor and launch your application as well, but it doesn't accomplish storing purposes.

Nonetheless, if you're looking for a storing mechanism other than a database like MySQL, PostgreSQL or Oracle, you could use MySQLite or XML files, just to name some.